# Angular4+PrimeNG+DropDown binding

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a simple task, I have a drop-down on drop-down change is have to display the selected name on the page. I am not getting how to do. I tried below code.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="languages" [(ngModel)]="selected"></p-dropdown>
selected language is {{selected}}

this.languages = [
            {label:'S', value:0},
            {label:'H', value:1},
            {label:'R', value:2},
            {label:'L', value:3},
            {label:'I', value:4},
            {label:'P', value:5}
        ];
```

But above code displays `value` instead of `label`. Can anyone please guide, where did I go wrong?